# Creating website with button that executes python script

Tags: python, web

My python program uses an input variable (a number 1-10) each day. Preferably, I want to create a simple website with only 1 input field (number) and a button which then executes the python script. Is there any easy way to do so? I don't have any experience with making websites.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I understand, you wish to create a website which has 1 input field  and a button visible on the frontend piece and on click of a button you need to run a python script.

1. You can write APIs to perform the same action and call the API using JQuery from frontend.
2. You can render html pages using python, by using its own routing techniques, check out video here https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=9MHYHgh4jYc

Answer (score 0):

Your requirements looks like you need to create a simple website. I feel you can use python frameworks like Flask or Django for this task. There are tons of tutorials available which can help you complete the challenge